# Multiple ui-view AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am working with ui-router, as I can achieve several views grouping different html, something like the image shows, ie a view 1 and another view 2. Additionally I want to see 2 only view with an authentication?

Any ideas?
[image]

My current code:

```
<div ng-include='"views/header.html"'></div>
<div ui-view></div>
<div ng-include='"views/footer.html"'></div>
```

Comment: did you solved or did something with this? Is the answer valid for you? Please, answer to close the question or improve the answers. Thanks!!

Comment: You seem to have at least one [other question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124902/ui-view-angularjs-multiple-views) (perhaps there are more?), but have not accepted an answer on any of them. The way things work around here is that we help you and then you accept an answer that helped, which will help others in future. I was going to upvote these good questions, but don't see I should, if you won't help others.

Answer (score 0):

Whether authentication on angular must be implemented on ui-router, it´s a little complicated to show it:

> **Step 1 - Define a variable like "authenticate" in your state provider**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('view1', {
        url: '/view1',
        templateUrl: 'app/tests/view1.html',
        controller: 'TestsCtrl1',
        authenticate: false
      });

      $stateProvider
      .state('view2', {
        url: '/view2',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/view2.html',
        controller: 'TestsCtrl2',
        authenticate: true
      });
  });
```

> **Step 2 - Change in client/app.js the method for $stateChangeStart. This will detect an stateChange, and check if the destination state
>   has the authenticated value on it.**
>   I did it in the run() function of the app

```
// Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
      Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
        //Check if next view (ui-state) requires authentication
        if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $rootScope.lastState=next.name;
          $state.go('login');
        } 
      });
    });
```

> **Step 3 - Create Different html template for each view:**

```
//view1.html

<div ng-include='"views/headerA.html"'></div>
<div ng-include='"views/contentA.html"'></div>
<div ng-include='"views/footerA.html"'></div>

//view2.html

<div ng-include='"views/headerB.html"'></div>
<div ng-include='"views/contentB.html"'></div>
<div ng-include='"views/footerB.html"'></div>
```

Hope it helps