# ui-view AngularJs multiple views

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ui-roter. I have two groups of pages. Group A and Group B. In each group the `header` and `footer` are repeated but the `content` changes. How can I do not to repeat the header and footer in each group ?. Is there a way to make the code simpler? Try a variable but it did not work for me.

My index.html

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
<div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

**Group A**

```js
$stateProvider
        .state('inicio', {
            url: '/inicio',
            views: {
                'header': {templateUrl: 'views/header.html'},
                'content': {templateUrl: 'views/inicio.html'},
                'footer': {templateUrl: 'views/footer.html'}
            }
        });

    $stateProvider
        .state('seguroPersonas', {
            url: '/seguroPersonas',
            views: {
                'header': {templateUrl: 'views/header.html'},
                'content': {templateUrl: 'views/seguroPersonas.html'},
                'footer': {templateUrl: 'views/footer.html'}
            }
        });

    $stateProvider
        .state('seguroEmpresas', {
            url: '/seguroEmpresas',
            views: {
                'header': {templateUrl: 'views/header.html'},
                'content': {templateUrl: 'views/seguroEmpresas.html'},
                'footer': {templateUrl: 'views/footer.html'}
            }
        });
```

**Group B**

```js
$stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            views: {
                'header': {templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/headerDashboard.html'},
                'content': {templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/inicioDashboard.html'},
                'footer': {templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/footerDashboard.html'}
            }
        });

    $stateProvider
        .state('clientesPotenciales', {
            url: '/dashboard/clientesPotenciales',
            views: {
                'header': {templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/headerDashboard.html'},
                'content': {templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/clientesPotenciales.html'},
                'footer': {templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/footerDashboard.html'}
            }
        });

    $stateProvider
        .state('seguroEmpresas', {
            url: '/seguroEmpresas',
            views: {
                'header': {templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/headerDashboard.html'},
                'content': {templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/actualizacionDatos.html'},
                'footer': {templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/footerDashboard.html'}
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your page has two high-level states: A and B. It's a good idea for Your state configuration to reflect that. Secondly, ui-router doesn't have to be aware of all content that is static (as in, it doesn't change within a state).

You are looking for a structure like this:

**index.html**

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

**a.html**

```
<header-a></header-a>
<ui-view></ui-view>
<footer-a></footer-a>
```

Same goes for b.html

The file with state configuration will then look something like this:

```
var aState = {
  url: '/a',
  templateUrl: 'path/to/a.html'
}

var inicioState = {
  url: '/a/inicio',
  templateUrl: 'views/inicio.html'
}

...

var bState = {
  url: '/b'
  templateUrl: 'path/to/b.html'
}

...

$stateProvider
      .state('a', aState)
      .state('a.inicio', inicioState)
      .state('b', bState)
...
```

The idea is, that You have a top-level state, which changes between Your two groups, A and B. Within them, You will have a static header and footer (provided e.g. as an angular directive) and a dynamic content in between them provided through a nested state. Now that You have a single `<ui-view>` tag in a html file, there is no need for implicitly-named views. Also, `$stateProvider` can chain the `state()` calls, this way You can lose some boilerplate.

Also, a proper practice for url naming is to follow the hierarchy of Your states. For example, Your state `clientesPotenciales` has an url `'/dashboard/clientesPotenciales'` which would indicate that it is a nested state of `dashboard`. In reality they remain on the same level. You should either change the url to `'/clientesPotenciales'`, if it's not nested, or change the state name to `dashboard.clientesPotenciales`.

Comment: sorry for the ignorance, I have to create the folder `path/to`? `path/to/a.html`

Comment: The `path/to` indicates whatever path Your new files containing the templates for Groups A/B will have. So, if You put the new file `a.html` in catalog `views` the path will be: `views/a.html`.

Comment: Ok I'm clear on the pata/to. I've tried but it does not work. will have something to do 'a.inicio' where does this come from? should I name them beforehand?

Comment: `a.inicio` is just a name for one of your states. This indicates that `inicio` is a nested state of `a`. You already provide the name and configuration through `$stateProvider` in the `state()` function. Keep in mind that my answer is not a full copy-paste solution. You need to complete the file with states' configuration and provide necessary templates (for `a.thml`, `b.html`)

Comment: Thank you. If I understand that it is only an example. I continued testing and worked but modifying the path `'/a/inicio'` for `'/inicio'`. 

I do not know if it's the right thing to do but it's the only way it worked.

Comment: "`it's the only way it worked`" - so, why did you not accept the answer? @pkowalcze helped you, so why not help others by indicating that this is the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the resource of AngularJS named components, it was released on 1.5 version and is a special kind of directive, a shorthand for a html element. With this, you can reuse your footer and header.

Official documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Example:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('yourApp')
        .component('headerCard', {
            templateUrl: 'your-path/header-card.html',
            controller: headerCardCtrl,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindings: {
            }
        });

    function headerCardCtrl() {
        var vm = this;

        // Your logic

    }

})();
```

At your controller template, you just use like this:

```
<header-card></header-card>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll see the documentation, I'm still not familiar with this.